# How to share folder with Windows 10 guest using virt-manager (KVM)?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, shared-folders, virt-manager

[These instructions](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/9p_virtio) for sharing host files with a guest are not working because there is no `/usr/bin/qemu-kvm`.

Comment: The page you linked also helps with folder sharing through virt-manager. But this relates to linux guests; windows guests do not seem to work this way (see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86071/use-virt-manager-to-share-files-between-linux-host-and-windows-guest)

Answer (score 10):

You can not add a shared folder in virt-manager like it is described in your article because the filesystem passthrough doesn't work well with a windows guest.

To solve your problem you have several options:

1. You can share a folder in the local network at your linux host system via SAMBA and access it over the windows filesystem directly.
2. You can use `spice-webdav` to share a folder like it is described in [this article from Guy Rutenberg](https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2018/10/25/sharing-a-folder-a-windows-guest-under-virt-manager/). This is not recommend for transferring large files.
3. If you only want to transfer data one or two times instead of having a permanent shared folder you can pack the data in your host system into a `.iso` file and add it in virt-manager as a disc to access it in the windows guest system.

Comment: Please consider explaining “doesn’t work well”. Is it possible to make it work (even partially)? Why not, if not? What fails?

Answer (score 3):

To save people time this is full steps to make it happned
download spice-webdav from [here](https://www.spice-space.org/download/windows/spice-webdavd/)
this is latest build :-

https://www.spice-space.org/download/windows/spice-webdavd/spice-webdavd-x86-latest.msi
https://www.spice-space.org/download/windows/spice-webdavd/spice-webdavd-x64-latest.msi

Install it in the guest machine *(use **Brasero** to create iso file)* ,
after install check if

> Spice webdav proxy” service is actually running (via services.msc) [reff](https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2018/10/25/sharing-a-folder-a-windows-guest-under-virt-manager/)

Inside the guest machine run `C:\Program File\SPICE webdavd\map-drive.bat` to map your host  shared folder, which is by default `~/Public`

Comment: What happens at the end? Does a new drive letter appear? It doesn't work in my case (Debian 11 as host and Win10 as guest). No errors but also no new drives.

Answer (score 3):

It's easy to start ssh server on host linux, while it's easy to run ssh client on windows.

run `systemctl start sshd` on linux and then run winscp on guest: windows 7

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, as @Salem F said, download the latest spice-webdav from https://www.spice-space.org/download/windows/spice-webdavd/

But before your run `C:\Program File\SPICE webdavd\map-drive.bat` you have to do a couple things:

1. With the VM off, go the settings for the VM and Add Hardware
2. Choose Channel, and set the new device name to `org.spice-space.webdav.0` and leave the other fields as-is
3. Start your VM as you would with virt-manager
4. Once running, run virt-viewer from your linux host (it should detect your running qemu VM), select your VM from the list, and connect to it.
5. In your Windows VM, run services.msc
6. Scroll down to Spice webdav proxy and double-click it, set Startup type to automatic, then click start (it would fail to start if I didn't first switch to virt-viewer from virt-manager).
7. Now run `C:\Program File\SPICE webdavd\map-drive.bat` and you should see the drive letter appear in File Explorer

Here is a link to a past that helped: https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2018/10/25/sharing-a-folder-a-windows-guest-under-virt-manager/